# Invalid state Error on websockets when sending message

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm working on app which send message via websockets (managed by django channels) and in return it receives json from django db as a message and renders frontend based on that json.
I have Invalid State Error when I try to send message by websocket, why?   Messages send are usually Json. I works properly all the time but commented part doesn't and I don't know why please explain me.

```
function main() {
      configGame();
    }
    
    function configGame() {
      const socket = "ws://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
      const websocket = new WebSocket(socket);
      const playerName = document.querySelector(".playerName_header").textContent;
    
      function asignEvents() {
        const ready_btn = document.querySelector(".--ready_btn");
        const start_btn = document.querySelector(".--start_btn");
        ready_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let mess = JSON.stringify({
            player: playerName,
            action: "ready",
          });
          sendMess(mess);
        });
        start_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let mess = JSON.stringify({
            player: playerName,
            action: "start",
          });
          sendMess(mess);
        });
      }
    
      function openWebsocket() {
        console.log("Establishing Websocket Connection...");
        websocket.onopen = () => {
          console.log("Websocket Connection Established!");
        };
      }
    
      function setWebsocket() {
        websocket.onmessage = (mess) => {
          console.log(`Message:  ${mess.data}`);
          dataJson = JSON.parse(mess.data);
          dataJson = JSON.parse(dataJson.message);
          //Player Ready (jeszcze z max_players zrobic kontrolke)
          if (dataJson.action === "player_ready") {
            const playersReadyText = document.querySelector(".players_ready_text");
            playersReadyText.textContent = `Players ready: ${dataJson.players_ready}`;
          }
        };
    
        websocket.onclose = () => {
          console.log("Websocket Connection Terminated!");
        };
      }
    /*
      function checkState() {
        let mess = JSON.stringify({
          player: playerName,
          action: "game state",
        });
        sendMess(mess);
      }
    */
      function sendMess(messText) {
        websocket.send(messText);
      }
      openWebsocket();
      checkState(); //This one doesn't work 
      asignEvents();
      setWebsocket();
    }
    
    // Asigning Event Listneres to DOM ELEMENTS
    function asignEvents() {
      const ready_btn = document.querySelector(".--ready_btn");
      const start_btn = document.querySelector(".--start_btn");
      ready_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Ready");
      });
      start_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Start");
      });
    }
    
    main();
```

Error:

Console (Safari) returns InvalidState error and points to
method checkState and sendMess.

```
InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the websocket **connected**?

```
sendMess(messText) {
    if (websocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        websocket.send(messText);
    } else {
        console.warn("websocket is not connected");
    }
}
```